# Is button.app-submit a valid jquery selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, dom

Is `$('button.app-submit')` a valid jQuery selector? If so, can you please explain which part is the class or id and how the html would look like.

Comment: not sure why my question was voted down, it's a bit discouraging when someone is trying to learn something and is asking even the simplest questions

Comment: May I ask what resource you are learning from? Seems it should definitely have covered it

Comment: Did you try it? If you hover over the downvote button (at least with the rep to downvote), it says "This question **does not show any research effort**; it is unclear or not useful." (Emphasis mine) You clearly didn't research it at all -- so far as I can tell, you could whip up an example to test this _very_ quickly, and Google would probably help.

Comment: It is going to be voted down because this information is easily available through a google search. It is generally recommended that you try to find the answer on your own before asking the community. Here are some resources that can better help you understand selectors in JQuery  https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/ http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_selectors.asp

Comment: Also very easy to go to the jQuery API docs and read all about selectors and since they mostly follow css selector protocols to read up on those too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is valid selector and it does not have `id` component. With this selector, you are telling that among all `button`s select only the ones with `.app-submit` class.

An example for `id` selector would be: `$('#MyButtonId')`

Comment: great. the answer that i needed!